# Templated class - Enable if

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I'm trying to do a templated class that runs a function only in certain cases. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


template <class T, class U>
struct Typelist
{
    typedef T Head;
    typedef U Tail;
};

class NullType
{
};

typedef Typelist<int, Typelist<float, Typelist<char*, NullType> > > UsableTypes1;
typedef Typelist<short, Typelist<std::string, NullType> > UsableTypes2;

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

private:
    Typelist _types;
};


template<class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass()
{
    _types = T;
}

template<class T>
void MyClass<T>::print(T type)
{

}

MyClass<UsableTypes1> any;
```

I need to make the code compiler or not only if the variable I pass to the print() function is a type that is in one of the usable types. I know that probably I'll have to use std::enable_if to allow the code to compile or not if print is called with an incorrect type and std::is_same to check the types but I don't know how to combine that functions with a templated class.

This is a test class to help to explain what I want to achieve:

```
MyClass<UsableTypes1> one;

void TestMyClass()
{
    int int_val = 0;
    float flt_val = 0.1f;
    const char* char_val = "Hi";
    short short_val = 10;
    std::string str_val = "Hello";

    one.print(int_val); // OK
    one.print(flt_val); // OK
    one.print(char_val); // OK
                              //    one.print( short_val); // compile error
                              //    one.print( str_val ); // compile error
}
```

Specially I don't know how can I add to print() a non-T-type parameter.

I hope you can help me!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is a "usable type" ? Sometimes it is sufficent to just accept any type that compiles, in which case you dont need any extra check, if it compiles then the type is usable, no?

Comment: Any of the types in the variables UsableTypes1 and UsableTypes2.

I need that the program doesn't compile, I can't chose that :(

Comment: I dont really get what you want to do. Your `print` will only accept a `T` which for a `MyClass<UsableTypes1>` is only a `UsableTypes1`. I guess what you actually want is `print` accepting any of the types contained in `UsableTypes1`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And in case I call print with a type that is not contained in UsableTypes1 I need to have a compile error (no allow the code to compile basically)

Comment: if thats the only reason for `MyClass` to be a template you should consider plain overloads

Comment: anyhow `_types = T;` wont work as you expect

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? You have a class and it should have a `print` method that accepts a `int`, `char*` or a `float` ?

Comment: I want to achieve a class that has a list of types allowed (for example int, float and char* but they can be any type) and a print function that only works if I pass as parameter one of those types. I'm going to add to my question a function that can help to explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have a good reason for using recursive `Typelist`s to contain your list of types. A more straight forward way would be to make `Typelist` a variadic template.

Then we can add a `constexpr` function that returns true if a given type is part of the `Typelist`.

`std::disjunction` requires `c++17`, but something equivalent can be written for `c++11` with a recursive template. That will however be more verbose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct NullType {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Typelist {
    using Head = T;
    using Tail = U;
    template <typename Type>
    static constexpr bool IsUsable() {
        return std::is_same<Type, T>::value;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... U>
struct Typelist<T, Typelist<U...>> {
    using Head = T;
    using Tail = Typelist<U...>;
    template <typename Type>
    static constexpr bool IsUsable() {
        return std::is_same<Type, T>::value || Typelist<U...>::template IsUsable<Type>();
    }
};

using UsableTypes1 = Typelist<int, Typelist<float, Typelist<const char*, NullType>>>;

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void print(U u) {
        static_assert(T::template IsUsable<U>(), "That is not a usable type");
        std::cout << u << std::endl;
    }
};

MyClass<UsableTypes1> one;

int main()
{
    int int_val = 0;
    float flt_val = 0.1f;
    const char* char_val = "Hi";
    short short_val = 10;
    std::string str_val = "Hello";

    one.print(int_val); // OK
    one.print(flt_val); // OK
    one.print(char_val); // OK
                              //    one.print( short_val); // compile error
                              //    one.print( str_val ); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to have a recursive Typelist. I'm trying to resolve a problem with some specifications. Anyway, I'll mark your answer as correct because is a solution too! Thank you

Comment: @CarlosHdezBarbera Updated my answer to use recursive `Typelist`s and to work with `c++11`.